# Eager load associations with Active Model Serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, associations, eager-loading, active-model-serializers

## Background

I have a rails application with deeply nested associations.

```
                          .-< WorkPeriod
Timecard -< Week -< Day -<--< Subtotal
                          `-< Adjustment

-<  (has many)
```

I'm using [Active Model Serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) to build out the API.

On the client side I want to load a timecard and all it's associations in one shot.

Currently my serializers look like this,

```rb
class TimecardSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, include: true
  has_many :weeks
end
class WeekSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, include: true
  has_many :days
end
# ... etc ...
```

## Problem

This all works find, except nothing gets eager-loaded. So it ends up making lots of calls to the database for each request. For each week, it makes a separate request for the days in that week. And for each day, it makes a separate request for it's work_periods, subtotals, and adjustments.

Answer (score 13):

One solution is to define your own `weeks` method on the TimecardSerializer. From there you can `.includes()` all the associations you want to eager load.

```rb
class TimecardSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, include: true
  has_many :weeks

  def weeks
    object.weeks.includes(days: [:sub_totals, :work_periods, :adjustments])
  end
end
```

All the queries will still show up in the log but most will be a cached query instead of a real one.

Comment: This is fine for loading a single resource, but won't work if this serializer is used to return a list of `Timecard`s.  In particular, the `weeks` won't be eagerly loaded, although the `weeks`' associations will be.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue.  I fixed it in my controller.  I like the idea of putting it in the serializer, but having it in the controller catches the n+1 weeks problem created by the ArraySerializer too.

```
Timecard.find(params[:id]).includes(weeks: [{ days: [:sub_totals, :work_periods, :adjustments] }])
```

and

```
Timecard.includes(weeks: [{ days: [:sub_totals, :work_periods, :adjustments] }])
```

should now eager load and limit the query to just six db hits.

Comment: you can't call includes on a instance, you should do `Timecard.where(id: params[:id]).includes(...)`