# Rails API requests extremely slow -> 300+ sec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, newrelic

My application suddenly became really slow with response time that can go up to 3 minutes. I have tried on two different local environment to make sure it is not being slowed down by the CPU/RAM or any other hardware component, but the problem remains.

### Some contexts

I am using **ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4.0.0**. **Pow** as a rack server and a **PostgreSQL** database.
The request used for this test is a basic API call to fetch all entries in an `entries` table.
The table itself doesn't have many records (~12k).

[image: Postman API request]

And here is the what the log shows for that request:

```
Started GET "/en/*****/api/v1/entries.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-11 11:42:13 +0100
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by Api::V1::EntriesController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"subdomain"=>"cms", "not"=>[:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy], "locale"=>"en", "tenant"=>"*****"}
...
...
...
...
Completed 200 OK in 309341ms (Views: 307471.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1620.3ms)
```

Yes you read it well... 299 seconds for the view rendering.

### Entries action

**Api::V1::EntriesController#index** is fairly simple

```
  def index  
    # Set Status
    @status = params[:status].present? ? status_id("#{params[:status]}") : [0..3]

    # Set Promoted
    @promoted = params[:promoted].present? ? params[:promoted] : [true,false]

    # Fetch Entries   
    @entries = Entry.where(status_id: @status, promoted: @promoted).filter_by_tag(params[:tag]).order("published_at DESC").paginate( page: params[:page], per_page: params[:limit] )
    respond_with @entries
  end
```

[image: New Relic Preview]

[image: New Relic Details]

And finally the SQL reports:

[image: New Relic SQL reports]

As you can see above, the **SQL queries duration and timestamp do not match**. Even though queries don't take long, the timestamp increase very quickly (until 300 seconds at the end).
I will spare you the details but the long list of queries (thanks to *acts-as-taggable-on*) does not show any weird or long unexpected queries. The longest query takes 300ms.

### development.rb

```
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Disable color for log file
  config.colorize_logging = false
```

Pow and Rails logs don't show anything wrong. I bypassed *.dev* in the proxy settings of my ethernet adapter.

Any idea what could cause my app to slow down that much?

### Edit #1

Following *apneadiving* reply, I removed all association that could possibly slowing down my request.

It is now simplified to render a simple JSON array of IDs (~300 records).

*/app/controllers/api/v1/entries_controller.rb*

```
def index

  # Set Status
  @status = params[:status].present? ? status_id("#{params[:status]}") : [0..3]

  # Set Promoted
  @promoted = params[:promoted].present? ? params[:promoted] : [true,false]

  # Fetch entries
  @entries = Entry.where(status_id: @status, promoted: @promoted)
  respond_with @entries
end
```

*/app/serializers/entry_serializer.rb*

```
class EntrySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
end
```

Results is still more that 3 seconds for such a simple request...

```
Started GET "/en/*****/api/v1/entries.json?limit=2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-12 10:07:10 +0100
Processing by Api::V1::EntriesController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"limit"=>"2", "subdomain"=>"cms", "not"=>[:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy], "locale"=>"en", "tenant"=>"*****"}
  Account Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."domain" = '******' ORDER BY "accounts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.6ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (2.2ms)  INSERT INTO "sessions" ("cookie", "created_at", "domain", "locale", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["cookie", "Dn/aXXbbWG8t8A5ZYGVgsQ=="], ["created_at", Fri, 12 Sep 2014 09:07:11 UTC +00:00], ["domain", "*******"], ["locale", :en], ["updated_at", Fri, 12 Sep 2014 09:07:11 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
  ApiKey Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "api_keys".* FROM "api_keys" WHERE "api_keys"."account_id" = 2 AND "api_keys"."access_token" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  ApiKey Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "api_keys".* FROM "api_keys" WHERE "api_keys"."account_id" = 2 AND "api_keys"."access_token" = '****************' LIMIT 1
  Account Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."domain" = '*****' ORDER BY "accounts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  SQL (2.6ms)  UPDATE "api_keys" SET "count" = COALESCE("count", 0) + 1 WHERE "api_keys"."account_id" = 2 AND "api_keys"."id" = 2
  Entry Load (4.9ms)  SELECT "entries".* FROM "entries" WHERE "entries"."account_id" = 2 AND "entries"."promoted" IN ('t', 'f') AND (("entries"."status_id" BETWEEN 0 AND 3 OR 1=0))
Completed 200 OK in 3558ms (Views: 3246.6ms | ActiveRecord: 27.7ms)
```

Indexes of the **entries** table:

```
# \d entries
                                               Table "public.entries"
      Column       |            Type             |                             Modifiers                             
-------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
 id                | integer                     | not null default nextval('entries_id_seq'::regclass)
 title             | character varying(255)      | 
 slug              | character varying(255)      | 
 status_id         | integer                     | 
 promoted          | boolean                     | 
 published_at      | timestamp without time zone | default '2014-07-31 15:06:20.462154'::timestamp without time zone
 created_at        | timestamp without time zone | 
 updated_at        | timestamp without time zone | 
 account_id        | integer                     | 
 excerpt           | text                        | 
 user_id           | uuid                        | 
 extra             | hstore                      | 
 entry_views_count | integer                     | 
Indexes:
    "entries_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_entries_on_slug" UNIQUE, btree (slug)
    "entries_title" gin (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, title::text))
    "index_entries_on_account_id" btree (account_id)
    "index_entries_on_promoted" btree (promoted)
    "index_entries_on_status_id" btree (status_id)
    "index_entries_on_user_id" btree (user_id)
```

Comment: you have to go deep in your query but it must be too complex and without adapated indexes. Consider using caching at least

Comment: But the problem doesn't seem to come from the queries though `(Views: 307471.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1620.3ms)`. Any idea what could cause such a difference between the **Duration** and **Timestamp** in the New Relic SQL reports image?

Comment: well because of lazy loading, views appear to be the one responsible for slowlyness but the are not. To be sure, just add `.to_a` at the end of your query. It will be executed right away in the controller, no more in the view

Comment: good point. replacing `Entry.where(status_id: @status, promoted: @promoted).filter_by_tag(params[:tag]).order("published_at DESC").paginate( page: params[:page], per_page: params[:limit] )` with `Entry.where(status_id: @status, promoted: @promoted).filter_by_tag(params[:tag]).order("published_at DESC").paginate( page: params[:page], per_page: params[:limit] ).to_a` I got **Completed 200 OK in 102830ms (Views: 101043.8ms | ActiveRecord: 629.4ms)**

Comment: interesting, how do you generate your json

Comment: Have a look at this one -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451722/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-render-json-in-rails

Comment: @apneadiving using an ActiveModel serializer. There is nothing fancy in it that could slow down the app as far as I can see.

Comment: @Vimsha thanks! I am not only trying to just improve performance but to track down a bug that is significantly slowing down my app (300k ms...)

Comment: Ok so something that can hurt badly in views ins N+1 requests, do you call associations?

Comment: yes I call one `has_many` association in the serializer. Let me try to remove it. I did not make change to this file for ages though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to eager load data as much a possible to prevent N+1 from happening:

```
entries = Entry.where(status_id: @status, promoted: @promoted).filter_by_tag(params[:tag])
entries = entries.includes(:entry_fields).order("published_at DESC")
entries = entries.paginate( page: params[:page], per_page: params[:limit] )
```

`includes` [doc is here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations)

Comment: Thanks @apneadiving. I assume I need to add `def entry_fields object.entry_fields end` and a new `attributes :entry_fields` in my serializer? after doing so, the page loads faster but still take 12sec for only 350 records.

Comment: why didnt you keep the has_many in the serializer? you thin it skips the eager loading?

Comment: just tried with `has_many :entry_fields` instead and got the same load results :\

Comment: weird it should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134649/eager-load-associations-with-active-model-serializers

Comment: Thanks! I just edited my original question to add some details (Edit section).

Comment: I guess you should optmize your query `SELECT "entries".* FROM "entries" WHERE "entries"."account_id" = 2 AND "entries"."promoted" IN ('t', 'f') AND (("entries"."status_id" BETWEEN 0 AND 3 OR 1=0))` with indexes

Comment: I just added my list of indexes to the original question.