# Adding include argument to render method doesn't fix N+1 query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I've got the following models:

```
class Request < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :contact
    belongs_to :hub_post
end

class Contact < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :requests
    has_many :likes
end

class Like < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :hub_post
    belongs_to :contact
end

class HubPost < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :requests
    has_many :likes
end
```

In my `HubPostSerializer`, I have the following method:

```
def liked_by_current_contact
    scope.present? && object.likes.where(contact_id: scope.id).present?
end
```

In my `RequestsController` I grab the requests with their `hub_posts` and `likes` and then return a JSON response (I'm using [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) 0.10.4 with the `:json` adapter) like so:

```
requests = current_contact.requests.includes(hub_post: [:contact])

# More controller code here

respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: requests, each_serializer: PortalRequestSerializer, scope: current_contact }
end
```

This is of course an obvious N+1 problem (which the Bullet gem surprisingly doesn't seem to pick up on). When viewing the logs I can see a `SELECT` statement for each hub_post. Now I've tried including `likes` like so:

```
requests = current_contact.requests.includes(hub_post: [:contact, :likes])
requests = current_contact.requests.includes(hub_post: [contact: [:likes]])
```

What's interesting is that the [Bullet](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) gem doesn't pick up on the N+1, yet [Scout](https://scoutapp.com) does.

I've also tried adding an `include` argument to my render method as per the [documentation](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/adapters.md#included), like so:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: requests, include: 'hub_posts,hub_posts.likes', each_serializer: PortalRequestSerializer, scope: current_contact }
end
```

I also tried using single-level and multi-level wildcards like so:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: requests, include: '*', each_serializer: PortalRequestSerializer, scope: current_contact }
end

respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: requests, include: '**', each_serializer: PortalRequestSerializer, scope: current_contact }
end
```

Yet nothing I do seems to eliminate the N+1. I'm not sure if this is a problem with how the gem handles included relations in nested serializers or if I'm just missing something.

**UPDATE**

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/danielbonnell/78b7225d7dab5bfa52e08ca2bd580c3f) of the query from the server log.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you should change your `includes` statement from

```
requests = current_contact.requests.includes(hub_post: [:contact])
```

to

```
requests = current_contact.requests.includes(:hub_post, :contact)
```

Comment: Nope. Tried this, didn't do anything for me.

Comment: I think there's some confusion. Is it `likes` you're having the N+1 issue with, or `hub_posts` and `contacts`?

Comment: Looking at your associations, I'm not quite sure why you are trying to nest `contacts` under `hub_posts` (`requests = current_contact.requests.includes(hub_post: [:contact, :likes])`) when `requests` are directly associated to `contacts` and `hub_posts` are not

Comment: HubPost also belongs_to :contact because a Contact can create a HubPost, but a HubPost can also be created by an Employer. I just omitted that line because I didn't think it was relevant. The N+1 problems isn't with hub_posts or contacts but with likes, which belong_to :contact and :hub_post. However if you look at my HubPost serializer method you will see that I am querying `object.likes` where `object` is an instance of HubPost. Let me know if that's still not clear

Answer (score 0):

I assume your Request model has `contact_id` to store id of current_contact, so you can try:

```
request = Request.where(contact_id: current_contact.id).includes(:contact, { hub_post: :likes })
```

Comment: This didn't do anything for the N+1 issue. I've tried every variation of placing `:likes` within the `includes` statement but nothing works

Comment: Edited my question above with a link (end of post) to a gist of the logs.

Comment: how about `request = Request.where(contact_id: current_contact.id).includes(contact: [:likes, :requests], hub_post: [:likes, :requests])`

Comment: Nope. I strongly suspect the problem isn't with the `includes` statement, but rather with how `active_model_serializers` handles nested associations. My theory is that for some reason it's "forgetting" that these nested associations (in this case, `likes`) were already included and is fetching them again.

Comment: @ACIDSTEALTH Take a loot at this PR, it may help you with some ideas https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/1672

Comment: and some others also useful [eager loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23814678/how-to-perform-eager-loading-in-active-model-serializers), [eager load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134649/eager-load-associations-with-active-model-serializers)